# Is the term Kaiser seen as offensive?

Tags: world-war-one, imperial-germany

Is the term Kaiser seen as offensive? Because I know the term means German Emperor, but according to Wikipedia it says that "During the First World War, anti-German sentiment was at its zenith; the term Kaiser—especially as applied to Wilhelm II, German Emperor—thus gained considerable negative connotations in English-speaking countries." and is this still the case nowadays?

Comment: Something having "Negative connotations" doesn't automatically mean that it is viewed as "offensive". I'd imagine that "Kaiser" is viewed as very old fashioned these days, even in Germany.

Comment: This is a _current language usage_ question, & thus probably (much?) better suited to GermanSE?

Comment: I can investigate migration to German.SE or to English, but this question seems inherently subjective, and therefore inappropriate for any SE site.    How would you test any answers to determine whether they are opinions or whether it is an [authoritative answer](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4274/26786)?

Comment: I don't think Franz Beckenbauer is or was offended when called Kaiser

Comment: German Stack Exchange does not really have a problem wirh answering questions about connotations (e.g. [does Puffmutter have negative connotations](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/63442/the-exact-german-word-for-addressing-a-woman-with-higher-academic-social-status)), but this question seems to be more about English language usage?

Comment: @FaridJamil, I can migrate this to English Language & Usage stack exchange, but only if you can update the question to document the research you've done (hint: Just stick in a statement that you checked a dictionary and didn't get clarity.)

Comment: Also may be worth noting that 1) the referenced Wikipedia article is labelled "needs citation", so I'm not confident that the term _was_ offensive, and 2) the fact that something was offensive in the past is not a strong predictor of currently offensive.   Quite frankly, I don't believe the term is offensive, except where the context makes it clear that there is an intent to belittle/offend.

Comment: [ELU mod here] With regard to research, **this must be listed.** You need to say *where* you searched, *what* you found, and *why* it doesn't help. It may be that you looked in several potential sources and found nothing; that's fine, but please be specific.

Comment: If a term only applies to a single human being, and is dragged through the mud cheifly due to the actions of that one human being, that isn't it becoming "offensive". That is, as they say, merely "sparkling consequences".

Comment: @Farid Jamil The German title of Kaiser comes from Caesar and is pronounced similarly.  During WWI, the monarchs of the German Empire and Austria-Hunary had the title of Kaiser, and the monarch of Bulgaria the title of tsar.  On the other side the monarch of Russia had the title Tsar, and the KIng of the UK as Emperor of India had the title of Kaiser-i-Hind.  So both sides in WWI had kaisers and tsars.

Answer (score 2):

**It's not offensive to use the word, but it has negative connotations.**

Although "Kaiser" is (or was) used for the rulers of several Germanic countries, in the English speaking world the word is primarily associated with the WWI ruler of Germany. Using it in another context (except for historical contexts of rulers who actually used that title) would be unusual.

Since WWI Germany and its ruler are popularly regarded as aggressive and militaristic (regardless of the truth of that view) to call someone a "Kaiser" would in effect be to call them aggressive and militaristic. In that sense the connotations of the word are negative.

In North America the [Kaiser roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiser_roll) (or Kaiser bun) is a kind of crusty bread roll, and in that sense the term is neither offensive or negative.

Mere use of the word, as opposed to calling someone by it, is not offensive.

Comment: As an example of non offensive use see English rock band Kaiser Chiefs

Comment: And American Kaiser restaurants

Answer (score 1):

In German it is not considered offensive, since most can distinguish between the title itsself and a single person who once held that title.

The term itsself comes from **Caesar** (pronounced as [ˈkae̯sar] in latin).

In the german version of the Wikipedia page (which incorporates the english pages of [Kaiser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiser) and [Emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor)) it explains where the term comes from in a more predominant manor than the english page.

---

> [Kaiser](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiser)
> <sub>Herrschaftstitel, abgeleitet vom lateinischen Eigennamen des Gaius Iulius Caesar</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Die deutsche Titelbezeichnung **Kaiser** (weiblich **Kaiserin**) leitet sich vom Namen des römischen Politikers [Gaius Iulius Caesar](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaius_Iulius_Caesar) ab, der am Ende der römischen Republik als De-facto-Staatsoberhaupt fungierte. Die Herrschaft und selten auch der Herrschaftsbereich werden entsprechend als Kaisertum bezeichnet. In der Antike hießen seit der Zeit des Augustus, des Großneffen Caesars, die Herrscher des Römischen Reichs Imperator Caesar Augustus (siehe auch Prinzipat und Spätantike). Während im Oströmisch-Byzantinischen Reich das Kaisertum bis 1453 existierte, erlosch das weströmische Kaisertum je nach Standpunkt im Jahre 476 oder 480.
>
> > **Kaiser**
> > <sub>Reign title, derived from the Latin proper name of Gaius Iulius Caesar</sub>
> >
> > ---
> >
> > The German title **Kaiser** (female **Kaiserin**) is derived from the name of the Roman politician [Gaius Iulius Caesar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar), who served as de facto head of state at the end of the Roman Republic.  The dominion and rarely also the dominion are accordingly referred to as empire.  In ancient times, since the time of Augustus, Caesar's great-nephew, the rulers of the Roman Empire were called Imperator Caesar Augustus (see also Principate and Late Antiquity).  While in the Eastern Roman-Byzantine Empire the empire existed until 1453, the Western Roman empire died out in 476 or 480, depending on your point of view.

---

**Sources**:

- [Kaiser – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiser)

  - [Kaiser – Wikipedia (English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiser)
- [Gaius Iulius Caesar – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaius_Iulius_Caesar)

  - [Gaius Iulius Caesar (English) – Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar)
- [Emperor - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor)

Answer (score 0):

The German title of Kaiser comes from Caesar and is pronounced similarly.  During WWI, the monarchs of the German Empire and Austria-Hunary had the title of Kaiser, and the monarch of Bulgaria the title of tsar.  On the other side the monarch of Russia had the title of tsar, and the KIng of the UK as Emperor of India had the title of Kaiser-i-Hind.  So both sides in WWI had kaisers and tsars.

So it would have beene extrmely illogical during WWI for someone to object to the title of kaiser (or tsar) and consider it objectionable because a monarch on the other side used the title of kaiser, since a monarch on their own side also had the title of kaiser.

World War I was a long time ago and by now most people in the various Euorpean countries have mostly forgiven their former enemies in the more recent World War II.

So I don't think that many people find the title "kaiser" objectionable.

I don't think that anyone would object to someone playing or singing the Kaiserhymne of Austria, for example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gott_erhalte_Franz_den_Kaiser

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w81MS8qDb80

Comment: By that logic, would "führer" or "duce" be more objectionable than "leader"?

Comment: @Jan Yeah, it would, führer at least.  Is it ever used in English except to refer to, or possibly compare someone else, to Hitler?  That's rather objectionable.  Duce is probably more obscure to someone less historically educated.